# Metadata error trying to install scipy on mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get the following error:

error: metadata-generation-failed

When I try to run:

pip3 install scipy

And I don’t know what to do!

I’ve tried updating pip and I feel like I’ve tried every way under the sun to install this thing. I’ve looked up the error and couldn’t find anything related to scipy and I also just looked up ways to troubleshoot installing scipy.

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Am I safe to assume that you’re working on an Apple Silicon Mac (M1 / M2)?

There are still some restrictions in the compatibility here. But the change notes of version 1.7.3 upwards include:

> SciPy 1.7.3 is a bug-fix release that provides binary wheels for MacOS arm64 with Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10. The MacOS arm64 wheels are only available for MacOS version 12.0 and greater.

So maybe check if you're using one of the supported Python versions and OS versions.

```
python3 --version
```

Good luck and cheers.

Comment: I'm using a 2015 Mac, so long before the silicon varieties. I'm using python 3.11.1 and my OS version is Mojave (before OS 12). Sounds like I can maybe fix my problems by installing an old version of scipy or perhaps updating my OS. Ideally I'd rather not update my OS since I've been advised against this for such an old computer, but I'm afraid tinkering with versions of python and other packages may cause other problems. It's all very frustrating since I had python and all its packages working before I had to wipe my hard dive and start with a fresh python.

Comment: oops- I just realized 3.11.1  is 3.eleven.1 not 3.one one.1 -- so my problem may be that my python is too new, which would make more sense given I just installed it

Comment: the newest python versions are often unsupported by heavy librarys that have many deps themselfes. I can recommend a dependancy management tool like poetry to avoid package mismatch.